# Neo4j unmanaged extension with Spring Data

Tags: spring, rest, neo4j

I was advised to develop Neo4j extension because of poor performance due to the many calls to the Neo4j REST interface introduced by Spring Data Neo4j. For the good start I was able to run simply Neo4j extension from Neo4j documentation:
http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/stable/server-unmanaged-extensions.html
Now I have to move some logic from my web service to Neo4j extension to make communication between them as small as possible. However, my web service is based on Spring Data Neo4j as well as Spring Data JPA, so to reuse my actual code I would like to use also Spring Data in my extension. I have found this documentation:
http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-neo4j/docs/current/reference/html/reference_neo4j-server.html
but it is not clear for me and there is no working example. Is there any sample code with such integration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a great example on using SDN in an unmanage extension, see http://inserpio.wordpress.com/2014/04/30/extending-the-neo4j-server-with-spring-data-neo4j/.